# iOS8 + SpriteKit. Can SKPhysicsJointSpring Not Be Attached Between Overlapping Nodes?

Tags: ios8, sprite-kit

I have a grid of disks (textured SKSpriteNodes) arranged in a grid above a background rectangle (textured SKSpriteNode):
[image]

I attrach a spring between background rectangle and each disk:

```
dotNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:scaleFactor * [dotNode radius]];

dotNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask    = EIDotNodeCategory;
dotNode.physicsBody.collisionBitMask   = (EIDotNodeCategory | EISceneNodeCategory);
dotNode.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = (EIDotNodeCategory | EISceneNodeCategory);

dotNode.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;

dotNode.physicsBody.density = 2.0;
dotNode.physicsBody.linearDamping = 0.01;
dotNode.physicsBody.restitution = 0.75;

SKNode *attachment = [dotNode.scene childNodeWithName:@"photoNode"];
SKPhysicsJointSpring *physicsJointSpring = [SKPhysicsJointSpring jointWithBodyA:attachment.physicsBody
                                                                          bodyB:dotNode.physicsBody
                                                                        anchorA:CGPointMake(dotNode.position.x, 8 + dotNode.position.y)
                                                                        anchorB:dotNode.position];

physicsJointSpring.damping = 0;
physicsJointSpring.frequency = 1;

[dotNode.scene.physicsWorld addJoint:physicsJointSpring];
```

Here are the physics setting for the background:

```
PhotoNode *photoNode = [PhotoNode photoNodeWithName:@"photoNode" texture:self.photoTexture shader:shader];
photoNode.zPosition = 2;
photoNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:photoNode.size];

photoNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask    = EIPhotoNodeCategory;
photoNode.physicsBody.collisionBitMask   = EISceneNodeCategory;
photoNode.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = EISceneNodeCategory;

photoNode.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
photoNode.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
photoNode.physicsBody.pinned = YES;
```

Here are the physics setting of the scene:

```
// get physical
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];

self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask    = EISceneNodeCategory;
self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask   = (EIDotNodeCategory | EIPhotoNodeCategory);
self.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = (EIDotNodeCategory | EIPhotoNodeCategory);
```

When I run the app I get this:

[image]

No spring behavior. No joy. What have I missed?

Comment: 0x141E Yep, joint attachment happens after the node is in the node tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable physics debug drawing. You'll see that your rectangles being dynamic bodies have moved along with the circles. You should make the rectangles static (dynamic = NO), preferably creating them as edge-loop shapes.

Comment: Not parsing your response. The background element is the only rectangle and it is pinned to the scene node. What rects are you referring to? Do you mean the disks? Please clarify. Thanks.

Comment: The photoNode is dynamic. Not sure if pinned is effective here, it depends on whether its parent has a physicsBody. Either way, enable physics debug drawing on SKView so you can better see what is truly going on.

Comment: Dots are children of the scene node. photoNode is a child of the scene node. All nodes have physicsBodies enabled. Scene provides gravity. Pinning the photoNode and disabling it's rotation fixes it in space. I still do not see why this should not just work. Further, why should the photoNode not be physical. Suppose I wanted it to rotate of be attached to something else with a spring, or whatever.

Comment: The photoNode needn't be dynamic and pinned, you can achieve the same more efficiently by creating the photoNode as static node by using the edgeLoopFrom... initializer. That'll make it an immovable physics body regardless of where it's pinned to.

Comment: Yes, but from a simulation perspective that rect have no effect. It never ever thought I would say this about an iOS framework but SpriteKit - while being a breeze for rendering - is looking virtually unusable for the most basic, trivial physics simulations. Just useless. Sigh ...

Comment: What do you mean by "no effect"? You can make the static body collidable or not collidable, it just depends on the category/collision bitmasks.